# Build failed... No build tools defined

Tags: avr-studio4

I am using avr studio 4.19 for debugging atmega128 development board. I added the path for tool-chain from project-configuration options. But still I am getting the same error while compiling/debugging.

Comment: 4.x? 7 is out, and it's free.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Microsite/atmel-studio/